# extending standard html table

Tags: html, events, methods, extend

Is there a way to extend a standard HTML table with certain methods and events ? In example, I would like it to recognize key press (up, down, pagedown, pageup, go top, go last, go left, go right). Is this possible ? many thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement it this way. Working as expected:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<style>
  table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  .selected {
    background-color: cyan;
    color: black;
  }
</style>  
<table id="browse">
  <tr style="background-color: blue; color:white"><th>First</th><th>Last</th></tr>
  <tr class="selected"><td>Homer</td><td>Simpson</td></tr>
  <tr><td>James</td><td>Webb</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Robin</td><td>Hood</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Bill</td><td>Gates</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Steve</td><td>Jobs</td></tr>
</table>
<script>
document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey( event )
{
  switch( event.keyCode )
  {   
    case 35: // go bottom
       curRow = document.querySelector( '.selected' );
       if( curRow != document.getElementById( "browse" ).rows[ document.getElementById( "browse" ).rows.length - 1 ] )
       { 
          curRow.className = "";
          curRow = document.getElementById( "browse" ).rows[ document.getElementById( "browse" ).rows.length - 1 ];
          curRow.className = "selected";
       }   
       break;

    case 36: // go top
       curRow = document.querySelector( '.selected' );
       if( curRow != document.getElementById( "browse" ).rows[ 1 ] )
       { 
          curRow.className = "";
          curRow = document.getElementById( "browse" ).rows[ 1 ];
          curRow.className = "selected";
       }   
       break;

    case 38:  // up
       curRow = document.querySelector( '.selected' );
       if( curRow != document.getElementById( "browse" ).rows[ 1 ] )
       {
          curRow.className = "";
          curRow = curRow.previousElementSibling;
          curRow.className = "selected";
       }   
       break;

    case 40:  // down
       curRow = document.querySelector( '.selected' );
       if( curRow != document.getElementById( "browse" ).rows[ document.getElementById( "browse" ).rows.length - 1 ] )
       { 
          curRow.className = "";
          curRow = curRow.nextElementSibling;
          curRow.className = "selected";
       }   
       break;

    case 33: // pageUp   
       curRow = document.querySelector( '.selected' );
       if( curRow != document.getElementById( "browse" ).rows[ 1 ] )
       { 
          curRow.className = "";
          curRow = document.getElementById( "browse" ).rows[ 1 ];
          curRow.className = "selected";
       }   
       break;

    case 34: // pageDown   
       curRow = document.querySelector( '.selected' );
       if( curRow != document.getElementById( "browse" ).rows[ document.getElementById( "browse" ).rows.length - 1 ] )
       { 
          curRow.className = "";
          curRow = document.getElementById( "browse" ).rows[ document.getElementById( "browse" ).rows.length - 1 ];
          curRow.className = "selected";
       }   
       break;

    default:
       alert( event.keyCode );   
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```